# Не могу написать скрипт в консоли Хрома

Tags: javascript

```
var star = '*';
for (i = 0;i==7;i=i+1){
```

Пишет такую ересь

```
VM769:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM675:895InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM675:828InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM675:694
```

Comment: `Пишет такую ересь` - это браузер в консоль выводит?

Comment: Извините за несмешную шутку. А можете весь скрипт выложить?

Comment: да, я просто набираю в консоли код,  после определения цикла пишет текст который ниже! Не давая закончить сам цикл !

Comment: У вас не закрыта скобка. Нужно так:  `var star = '*'; for (i = 0;i==7;i=i+1){}`

Comment: Так  тоже не работает  пишет undefine var star = '*'; for (i = 0;i==7;i=i+1){console.log(star * i)}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хром по умолчанию выполняет скрипт по <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Нажимайте <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> для переноса строк без выполнения.

Answer (score 3):

Да и сам цикл никогда не выполнится. Проблема в условии i == 7;

```js
var i;

for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Так цикл выполнится.